# Confused about how to properly create nested cloudformation stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, nested, stack, aws-cloudformation

Up until now, for my project, I had just a single cloudformation stack template. However, I recently encountered that limit for the number of bytes you can have in a stack template, which is why I've been looking into nested stacks. I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around the formatting though, because I've seen a lot of differences in the examples provided.

Below is a snippet of the original (non-nested) stack template before hitting the limit.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Template for wgs-pipeline"

Parameters:

  CloudspanLambdaFuncS3BucketName:
    Type: String

  CloudspanLambdaFuncS3KeyName:
    Default: 'sfn.deployable.zip'
    Type: String

  CloudspanLambdaFuncModuleName:
    Default: 'cloudspan'
    Type: String


Resources:

  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway

  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'

  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'

  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: EC2 Security Group for instances launched in 
the VPC by Batch
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'

# Lambda Resources (the section I want to place in a separate stack)

  CloudspanLambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CanListBuckets
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetBucketLocation"
                  - "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        - PolicyName: CanLog
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - logs:*
          Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*

  CloudspanLambdaFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler:
        Fn::Join: [ ".", [ Ref: CloudspanLambdaFuncModuleName, "handler"] ]
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ CloudspanLambdaExecutionRole, Arn ]
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Ref: CloudspanLambdaFuncS3BucketName
        S3Key:
          Ref: CloudspanLambdaFuncS3KeyName
      Runtime: "python3.6"
      Timeout: "60"
```

What I want to do is isolate everything under the "Lambda resources" comment into a separate stack ("lambda stack") and then have this master stack call to that separate "lambda stack".

Below is my current set-up attempt, but I don't know if I'm doing it correctly:

**Master template:**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Master template for wgs-pipeline. Contains network resources, lambda parameters, and batch 
              parameters"
Parameters:
  CloudspanLambdaFuncS3BucketName:
    Type: String
  CloudspanLambdaFuncS3KeyName:
    Default: 'sfn.deployable.zip'
    Type: String
  CloudspanLambdaFuncModuleName:
    Default: 'cloudspan'
    Type: String
Resources:
# The stuff that was already in the Resources section in the original stack
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref 'InternetGateway'
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: EC2 Security Group for instances launched in the VPC by Batch
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
# The section that is referencing a separate stack
  LambdaStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        LambdaFunction:
          # ref?
        LambdaExecutionRole:
          # ref?
      TemplateURL: # URL to S3 location of lambda stack
      TimeoutInMinutes: '60'
```

**LambdaStack template:**

```
---
AWSTEmplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Lambda functions stack, contains lambda function and lambda function execution roles.
Parameters:
  LambdaFunction:
    Description: the lambda function.
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Description: the lambda execution roles.
Resources:
  Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
  Properties:
    Handler:
      #
      # Need to figure out how to reference these since they are parameters that exist in the master template
      #
      Fn::Join: [ ".", [ Ref: CloudspanLambdaFuncModuleName, "handler"] ]
    Role:
      Fn::GetAtt: [ CloudspanLambdaExecutionRole, Arn ]
    Code:
      S3Bucket:
        Ref: CloudspanLambdaFuncS3BucketName
      S3Key:
        Ref: CloudspanLambdaFuncS3KeyName
    Runtime: "python3.6"
    Timeout: "60" # This will be included in the master stack?
Outputs:
  LambdaStack:
    Description: Lambda stack ID.
    Value:
      Ref: LambdaFunction
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-LambdaFunction"
  LambdaExecutionRoleStack:
    Description: Lambda execution role stack ID.
    Value:
      Ref: LambdaExecutionRole
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-LambdaExecutionRole"
```

Have I formatted the LambdaStack template and master template correctly so far? An in terms of the CloudspanLambdaFunction and CloudspanLambdaExecutionRole parameters that were in the original (un-nested) stack, how exactly do I format those in the LambdaStack (nested) template? Would it be just adding the two parameters under the resources section of the LambdaStack yaml?

Comment: Do you have an actual question? Are you getting any errors in particular that you would need guidance on?

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard: My question is whether I'm on the right track, because I feel like I might not have done the formatting part correctly, mainly for the LambdaStack template.

Comment: Indeed the formatting of the nested part is not correct. For exemples your Parameters need "Type" and your "Resources" lack Logical Ids. Think of nested template as completely normal templates. In fact, I sometime use a template as a child of another as well as an independent template. You can basically copy paste stuff from your original template directly without altering too much the template.